# SharedPreferences on update an Android App from google play data lost

Tags: dart, flutter

I've stored user settings in the SharedPreferences in my App, when I update the App via Google Play Store to a new version of the App data getting lost.

but if i store user settings in the SharedPreferences and then run google backup and then update the app via google play data getting restord and user setting updated in UI

any idea why its only working if i do auto backup?

Comment: Can you add value of attribute `android:allowBackup` of `application` tag from your AndroidManifest.xml to the question?

Comment: my file dose not have it, flutter create project dont add it as android default is set to true.